# display result of function is controller inside home view blade (LARAVEL , PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, controller

i want to show the total of amount in the home view blade
(table = payments , colon = amount)

i tested another method by route , this it work fine but the result show in /test of course:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
 $total = DB::table('payments') 
->where('status', '=', 'success')   //this for collect only the success payments
->sum('payments.amount'); 
return   $total;   //  work fine the result is correct
});
```

but my purpose is to display this result inside the home view 
by move the function from the previous code from route to controller and call it in the view

for the controller i have Homecontroller but the function index is aleardy used , so i create new function in this controller i try this

```
public function show(){
 $total = DB::table('payments') 
->where('status', '=', 'success') 
->sum('payments.amount'); 
return  view('home' , $total); 
}
```

for routing i put this

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@show');
```

i try this inside the view but didnt work :

```
<h1>{{$total}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can send total variable result with compact function to view like
>   below.

```
return  view('home' , compact('total'));

// You can call it in home.blade like this 

//for example

@if(isset($total ))
    <li>{{ $total }}</li>
@endif
```

Comment: how i call it from the home.blade ?

Comment: thank you but by what i replace the name  {{ $result->??}}

Comment: First you should dd($total) and then you can see what is key name .{{ $result->here is your array key value}}

Comment: in the function show i stored the result of total of payments in the variable $total.
i dont need aray i just need to display this total !
the result must be for exemple 6540.00

Comment: I edit my answer according to your need , now you can see it.

Comment: thank you any way , i change it the page is work but i cant find the element (ul) in the page and also in the source code , so i think that condition didnt work.
if that condition is correct maybe there is error in controller ??

Comment: no didnt work just the page show normaly without error  because the condition didnt pass , so chrome didnt generate the ul element (i change it to h4 but same thing) ,

Comment: Have you got your total variable value correct in your controller??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with()`

```
public function show(){
    $total = DB::table('payments')->where('status', '=', 'success')
                                  ->sum('payments.amount'); 
    return  view('home')->with('total', $total); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to documentation :

[The second argument is an "array" of data that should be made available to the view.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views)

try :

```
return  view('home' , ['total' => $total]);
```

or use `->with('key',$value)` :

```
return view('home')->with('total', $total);
```

you can also use [`compact()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function, it is an inbuilt function in PHP and used to create an array using variables:

```
return  view('home' , compact("total"));
```

Comment: how i call it from the home.blade ?

Comment: in the same way you done before : <h1>{{$total}}</h1>

Comment: didnt work ! the error page say : Undefined variable: total